# xclip not working when invoked from keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, xclip

I got the command:

`echo "myemial@gmail.com"| tr -d '\n' | xclip -selection c`

It works when I run it from the terminal. However, when I added it as custom keyboard shortcut nothing happens.

When I run it this way:

`terminator -e "echo 'email@gmail.com' | tr -d '\n' | xclip -selection clip; sleep 0.05"`

the shortcut works , but when I change the sleep value to 0.01 it stops working.

a) How can I debug why this shortcut not work?

b) why does the shortcut works when the command is called from terminator?

c) why it is time dependent?

d) where I can find detailed documentation about how shortcut works in ubuntu?

Comment: maybe if you run it in a shell `sh -c 'echo "myemial@gmail.com"| tr -d '\n' | xclip -selection c'`

Comment: As I wrote, I tested it in cmd.

Comment: dont think shortcut starts a shell so you may need to wrap your command with `sh -c ''`